# aaPanel: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: vue.js, qt, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I am running a Laravel script with .vue files, so I need to compile to see any change on my site. I'm running a clean installation of aaPanel on Ubuntu 23.10 btw

When I run 'npm run build' or 'vite build' via the command line, I'm getting the following error.

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

I've tried pretty much everything I could find via a Google search. Does anyone know how to fix this, so I'm finally able to compile?

The full log coming back by using **export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1** is as follows:

for '**npm run build**' https://pastecode.io/s/w9zd4cf5

for '**vite build**' https://pastecode.io/s/n44r0zd5